# What are the best UX seminars in USA, for beginners?

Tags: learning, training, conferences

I am pretty new to the whole UX realm of things and I am in the process of hiring an employee to manage the UX of the e-commerce sites I own. I know it's necessary to get a UX employee since I have four sites in all different countries and I also am planning to expand and I'd like to be able to work with a skilled professional instead of taking shots in the dark like I have been.

Either way, in helping me better understand the employee I'm hiring and being able to give him direction on what I want to do, I need to take a beginners course in UX design and UX navigation. I've been looking at the Nielsen Usability Week in NYC in February, and it seems like it's a highly respected event. But I just wanted to hear anyone's first hand experience with this, remember I'm a beginner in UX.

I know there are similar questions to this already that have been answered but I wanted to know since I am a beginner if it would be beneficial for me.

Main Goals I want to learn:

- Best practices for E-Commerce Sites UX
- How to simplify navigation
- How to analyze site metrics (Currently we analyze our site on so many different metrics, I believe that there has to be a better way to do this. We need to focus on more quantifiable data and the important data rather than ALL the data)

Comment: Good on you for educating yourself before hiring someone :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have never been to any in the USA, however I have been watching a lot of the videos from UX Week lately, and finding the content quite good.

http://uxweek.com/2012/

Answer (score 0):

Some of my friends took this [SCPD seminar at Stanford](http://scpd.stanford.edu/search/publicCourseSearchDetails.do?method=load&courseId=11894) and found it very helpful. I have not personally taken it but am planning to register for it this Autumn.